# Serialization error while creating Elastic Sink Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I got the below error while creating the elastic sink connector.

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR `testconnector` WITH(
    "type.name"= '_doc',
    "input.data.format"= 'AVRO',
    "connector.class"= 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
    "tasks.max"= '1',
    "transforms"= 'Dealership',
    "topics"= 'es.contact.model',
    "transforms.Dealership.type"= 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value',
    "transforms.Dealership.field"= 'indexTopicName',
    "transforms.Dealership.skip.missing.or.null"= 'true',
    "connection.url"= 'http://192.168.1.5:19200',
    "key.ignore"= 'true',
    "schema.ignore"= 'true'
    );
```

The error is,

```
 | FAILED | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:220)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:519)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:494)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$5(WorkerSinkTask.java:519)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:200)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing message to JSON in topic es.contact.model
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:322)
```

I used the below versions,
OS - Linux Cent OS 7
Confluent kafka version - 7.1.1
Elastic Sink Connector - 11.1.10

Kindly help me to fix this error.

Comment: You sure the port is 19200 and not 9200 ?

Comment: Please share what converters you're using for connect. I don't think `input.data.format` does what you want